# Compare 2 count aggregations

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in MongoDB that looks something like the following:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "type" : "start", userid: "101", placementid: 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "type" : "start", userid: "101", placementid: 2 }
{ "_id" : 3, "type" : "start", userid: "101", placementid: 3 }
{ "_id" : 4, "type" : "end", userid: "101", placementid: 1 }
{ "_id" : 5, "type" : "end", userid: "101", placementid: 2 }
```

and I want to group results by `userid` then `placementid` and then count the types of "start" and "end", but only when the two counts are different. In this particular example I would want to get `placementid: 3` because when grouped and counted this is the only case where the counts don't match.

I've written a query that gets the 2 counts and the grouping but I can't do the filtering when counts don't match. This is my query:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            userid: 1,
            placementid: 1,
            isStart: { 
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$type", "start"] }, 1, 0] 
            },
            isEnd: { 
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$type", "end"] }, 1, 0] 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { userid:"$userid", placementid:"$placementid" }, 
            countStart:{ $sum: "$isStart" },
            countEnd: { $sum: "$isEnd" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            countStart: {$ne: "$countEnd"}
        }
    }
])
```

It seems like I'm using the match aggregation incorrectly because I'm seeing results where `countStart` and `countEnd` are the same.

```
{ "_id" : {"userid" : "101", "placementid" : "1"}, "countStart" : 1.0, "countEnd" : 1.0 }
{ "_id" : {"userid" : "101", "placementid" : "2"}, "countStart" : 1.0, "countEnd" : 1.0 } 
{ "_id" : {"userid" : "101", "placementid" : "3"}, "countStart" : 1.0, "countEnd" : 0 }
```

Can anybody point into the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two fields inside `$match` stage you need [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) which is available in MongoDB 3.6:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            userid: 1,
            placementid: 1,
            isStart: { 
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$type", "start"] }, 1, 0] 
            },
            isEnd: { 
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$type", "end"] }, 1, 0] 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { userid:"$userid", placementid:"$placementid" }, 
            countStart:{ $sum: "$isStart" },
            countEnd: { $sum: "$isEnd" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: { $ne: [ "$countStart", "$countEnd" ] }
        }
    }
])
```

If you're using older version of MongoDB you can use [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/):

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            userid: 1,
            placementid: 1,
            isStart: { 
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$type", "start"] }, 1, 0] 
            },
            isEnd: { 
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$type", "end"] }, 1, 0] 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { userid:"$userid", placementid:"$placementid" }, 
            countStart:{ $sum: "$isStart" },
            countEnd: { $sum: "$isEnd" }
        }
    },
    {
        $redact: {
            $cond: { if: { $ne: [ "$countStart", "$countEnd" ] }, then: "$$KEEP", else: "$$PRUNE" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Oh, I was close. Thanks for the tip, it's working now :)

Answer (score 1):

You run do the following pipeline to get this - no need to use $expr or $redact or anything special really:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "userid": "$userid",
            "placementid": "$placementid"
        },
        "sum": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $eq: [ "$type", "start" ] },
                    then: 1, // +1 for start
                    else: -1 // -1 for anything else
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "sum": { $ne: 0 } // only return the non matching-up ones
    }
})
```